# Can I change the destination on a Lufthansa "Classic" fare?

Tags: tickets, lufthansa

I have Lufthansa's "Economy Classic" tickets and I can change dates on their website. It's impossible for me to contact their customer service right now.

Does somebody know if I can change **the route**?

For example, I have round trip NCE-MUC-KBP (Nice to Boryspil) and I want to change it for NCE-FRA-KRK (Nice to Kraków). I've read the conditions on their website but it's not clear and on the site I've found only how to change the date, not the destination.

Comment: This will only work on the goodwill of Lufthansa since you are not on the original route and thus only through contacting customer support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called to Lufthansa and they told me that itinerary cannot be changed in economy classic. But personally for me it's possible

Comment: It seems that it's because I use their services a lot and they can offer me something like a gift allowing to make changes